# After login I got redirected to home page Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-6

If I am not logged in I got redirected to /login page, after I got logged in I am redirected to /home, and I am not sure why. Because I must be redirected to a vue.js component.

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware('guest')->get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('auth')->get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('layouts.app');
});
```

**app.blade.php**

```
@auth
    <div id="app">
    </div>  
    <p>You are logged in!</p> <!-- When I am logged in I got this p.
@else
    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
@endauth
```

**app.js**

```
//with all imports

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from './components/Home/Home';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1):

`/home` is coming from **`RouteServiceProvider`**, there's a const called `HOME` that is used by **`LoginController`** to redirect the user after login.

You can just change the const in **`RouteServiceProvider`**:

```
/**
* The path to the "home" route for your application.
*
* @var string
*/
public const HOME = '/path-to-your-spa';
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention. In LoginController I changed $redirectTo with another path, but still the same.. Meanwhile I found out the problem. I forgot to import app ,and in routes my {any} didn't worked.